# how is flatMap working with custom monads

Tags: scala, monads

I am new in scala and confused with Monads' implementation. In the below program when "a <- g(3)" is executed the value of 'a' is 23 and not Writer, why? what is happening behind the scene?

```
case class Writer(value:Int, log:String) {
  def map(f:Int=>Int): Writer = {
    Writer(f(value), log)
  }
  def flatMap(f:Int=>Writer): Writer = {
    val temp = f(value)
    Writer(temp.value, log+"...."+temp.log)
  }
}

object Test extends App {

  def f(value: Int):Writer = {
    Writer(40+value, s"f has $value")
  }

  def g(value: Int):Writer = {
    Writer(20+value, s"g has $value")
  }

  val result1 = for {
    a <- g(3)
    b <- f(a)
  } yield b

  println(result1)

  val result2 = g(3) flatMap {
    a => f(a).map(b=>b)
  }

  println(result2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From scala docs `for comprehension`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html

> it is nothing more than a syntactic sugar for composition of multiple monadic operations

Your call

```
for {
    a <- g(3)
    b <- f(a)
  } yield b
```

gets de-sugared to:

```
g(3).flatMap { n =>
  f(n)
}
```

The desugaring is applied on the evaluated result of g(3). You can look at this as:

```
writer: Writer = g(3) // evaluation of g(3)

writer.flatMap { n => // flatMap on Writer
  here n is your value which is Int
...
```

So here `n` in the de-sugared is equivaluent to `a` in the syntax-sugar

Comment: but my confusion is with the return type of "g" and flapMap, as they are both Writer.

Comment: About this `flatMap(f:Int=>Writer): Writer`? If yes, what the signature means is, `flatMap` will take a function which returns a `Writer` which is the final return value of the `flatMap`

Comment: Right and same is true in case of def g(value: Int):Writer. So how for "a <- g(3)"  'a' became 23 instead of Writer?

Answer (score 0):

There's a generic interface for monads provided by cats library:

https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html

In this doc page you can find how to efficiently and correctly create your own monad. 
Besides, cats feature their own Writer monad, example usage:

https://medium.com/@spearsear/simple-use-of-cats-writer-monad-4a1694556112